# asp.net mvc 3 membership, cannot connect to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

I have installed visual studio 2010 as well as mvc 3 and have been working on a site.
Later I installed sql server 2008 and when I tried to register a user through provided membership in asp.net mvc i had bunch of errors saying that there was no data base or something like that, so through a lot of research i finally added the aspnetdb to my sql server and enabled remote accessing... and as of right now when i try to register i get this error: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

this is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated     Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I remember that some time ago working on my previous projects i had no problem with the membership provider and registering users loging in and so on.. so i'm really frustrated and don't know what i'm missing here.

Comment: does the .mdf file exist in the app_data folder of your project?

Comment: then where is the mdf that contains the aspnetdb you "enabled" on the server?

Comment: i don't know where it is, In sql server in databases folder I see the membership database, should i copy it to my app_data folder?

Comment: shouldnt it be added automatically when i start my website?

Comment: Why do you think that? You could copy the mdf file if you wanted and it should probably work. Give it a go.

Comment: tried to copy manually the file and paste it into the app_data folder and i get a message saying access dienied :\

Comment: you might to stop the sqlserver database prior to copying it and pasting into the app_data folder. Also, I would stop the web site prior to the cut and paste.

Comment: ok i got it to work, i had to set up the connection manually.. my connection string was a little messed up so thank you all for info and help

Answer (score 0):

You can use it directly from localhost, no need to put it in App_Data folder. Use this connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>    
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=*Name of your database*;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```